# Image upload with jquery

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to upload an image file from a partial view using AJAX but it is returning a Bad Request(400) error. I have searched SO answers but it is not working. Here is my script :

```
$("#prodImgUpload").change(function() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", $("#prodImgUpload")[0].files[0]);

        console.log(formData.get("file"));
        addAntiForgeryToken(formData);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("UploadImage","Product",new{area="admin"})",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {
                alert("Image uploaded successfully");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
        });
```

And here is the HTML :

```
<div class="upload-button">
<div class="label">Upload image</div>
<input asp-for="FileToUpload" id="prodImgUpload" name="FileToUpload" 
type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg, image/bmp" />
</div>
```

It never reaches the controller. And remember it is in partial view.
Here's my controller's action :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult UploadImage(IFormFile file)
    {
     if (file == null)
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "No file uploaded" });

        //do something with file.
    }
```

Comment: The fact that it's in a partial view is meaningless. JS runs client-side, long after the server has rendered all the views and returned a fully formed response. If you're getting a 400, there's something wrong with what you're posting, at least from the perspective of your action. Post your action.

Comment: @Chris Pratt I have included action. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not including the antiforgery token with the AJAX request. Reference the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery#javascript) for how to handle AJAX request with antiforgery tokens. Essentially, you need to add a header to your AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    headers: {
        "RequestVerificationToken": $('#RequestVerificationToken').val()
    },
```

The value comes from a hidden input added via:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions{
    public string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
    {
        return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
    }
}

<input type="hidden" id="RequestVerificationToken" 
   name="RequestVerificationToken" value="@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()">
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, you saved my day and providing me useful information as I am new in asp.net core.